# Elementary OS Juno - No sound on USB-C monitor

Tags: sound, release-juno

Laptop - Thinkpad T470

On Loki, when I connect my monitor via USB-C, I was able to select the monitor as a sound target.

In Juno, the monitor does not appear as a sound target. The sound options available are the laptop's internal speakers and headphones

The same issue occurs on HDMI as well.

Suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: i can confirm this with my HDMI monitor, maybe you want to [take a look here](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-sound/issues/65)

Answer (score 1):

GDog was correct, installing pavucontol is the workaround to this issue for now, Hopefully the Elementary team fixes this in the future!

sudo apt install pavucontrol
*run pavucontrol*
*In configuration, change the built in adio profile to digital stereo output*

done.

Thanks GDog!