# No sound in TV over HDMI in Juno

Tags: sound, release-juno, audio, hdmi

Today I installed Juno on a low-end 2016 Asus laptop with Intel i5 processor. I know nothing about Linux, this was just to replace a very slow Windows 10.

When I connect TV with HDMI, I get picture but no sound. I installed Pulse Audio Volume Control, as suggested on some Ubuntu forums, and when I manually chose "HDMI 2" as output, it worked. But only until the next time I connected the cable.

Any way to make it permanent? Is it possible to install some better drivers or software?

Comment: By the way, in the default Sound app I only see "Speakers" as output, no HDMI...

Answer (score 2):

We can use command

```
pactl
```

> pactl - Control a running PulseAudio sound server on terminal

first, list our available properties in our machine using this command:

```
    pactl list cards
```

[image]

based on my hardware above, i set output:hdmi-stereo as my default profile using this command:

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

if we want to set to internal output(in my case my laptop), use this command:

```
 pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo
```

and magically, in sound settings is gonna be like this.
[image: sound settings going normal again]

I hope this can help.more detail about pactl command use this command:

```
pactl -h
```

or check manual page:

```
man pactl
```

Comment: can't even give the command pactl so how to install that?

Comment: pactl included here : https://packages.debian.org/sid/pulseaudio-utils. You can install that from App Center.

Comment: This solved my problem even though the availability was set to no. Something must be done about this. Why the sound settings doesn't list the available profiles in the sound settings?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation (bug?) of the current sound setting app. The current workaround is to install `PulseAudio Volume Control` from the `AppCentre`, and to select a HDMI configuration profile.

[image: Select Profile from Configuration Tab]

References:

- [Related Stackexchange Issue](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16455/elementary-os-juno-no-sound-on-usb-c-monitor)
- [Related Github Issue](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-sound/issues/65)

Comment: Hi Ifaz. Thanks for your reply. Notice I already mention Pulse Audio in my original post, so I know about the workaround and it also works for me. It's just that it's totally inconvenient to set it every time you want to connect the HDMI cable.

Comment: Opps, I must have mixed this with another post which didn't already mention Pulse Audio when responding. I'm going to leave the response here for now for anyone looking for a step-by-step solution.

Comment: @IfazKabir I figured this out before seeing your answer, but also came at it slightly differently. I ran `aplay --list-devices` to see that the HDMI devices were recognized by the system, also `pactl list` to see they are available; then `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`, and selected one of the HDMI profiles for the Built-in Audio. At least you don't have to do that for Bluetooth headphones. I upvoted your answer because it would have probably helped if I found it earlier.